# OpenCV could not load needed library (face detection)

Tags: android, c++, opencv, android-ndk

I am using the face detection open cv for android sample.

There are no errors when building, however when deploying the sample I get runtime errors of

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: link_image[1940]: 150 could not load needed library 'libopencv_java3.so' for 'libdetection_based_tracker.so' (load_library[1095]: Library 'libopencv_java3.s0' not found)
```

I have added the ndk to the project, and linked the open cv library with the sample.

Comment: What you have here is a linker error. Is this the first openCV program you have tried to make? If so, your installation could be wrong, or java is not looking in the right places to find `'libopencv_java3.so'`. Also, at the end it mentions `Library 'libopencv_java3.s0' not found`. I don't think that should be a "0" in `s0`. But I rarely use java.

Comment: In your **Android.mk**, you probably have `OPENCV_LIB_TYPE:=SHARED`. I suggest that you try to use `STATIC` instead.

Answer (score 1):

After Doing these changes Working fine.

I got Image's faces are surrounded by rectangles

**Note:- 1. In Android Studio, go to File > New > Import-Module and the choose /sdk and wait for the sync to finish. 2.Do not import /sdk/java as most tutorials suggest.**

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `System.loadLibrary("opencv_java3");`. It worked good for me

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because android couldn't find libdetection_based_tracker.so in /**jniLibs** folder

solution for it is

1. copy **native/libs** folder from opencv-sdk in **/jniLibs**
2. make Android.mk file and Application.mk file in jni folder
3. Copy following line in your build.gradle

sourceSets.main {

```
jni.srcDirs = [] //disable automatic ndk-build call
jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/jniLibs'
```

}

buildTypes { ... }
and add

defaultConfig {...

```
ndk{
    moduleName "libdetection_based_tracker"
}
```

}

4.add libdetection_based_tracker.so to jniLibs